# Custom error handling Angular : Throwing specific errors

Tags: angular, rest, custom-errors

I tryed to do an error handling system in Angular but there is something that doesn't work and i don't get why. When the instance of BadRequest is returned to the component, the component doesn't seems to recognize it with `error instanceof BadRequest`, and it throws the unexpected error handler instead.

Data Service :

```
  create(ressource){
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(ressource)).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  public handleError(err: Response){
    if (err.status == 400 ){
      return Observable.throw(new BadRequest(err));

    } else if (err.status == 404) {
      return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError(err));

    } else {
    // Return error by default if no specific error
    return Observable.throw(new AppError(err));
    }
  }
```

Component

```
  createCategorie(input: HTMLInputElement) {

    this.service.create(categorie)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
        },
        (error: AppError) => {

          if (error instanceof BadRequest) {
            this.sharedSnackBarMessage.changeMessage("This caterogy already exists");
            this.snackBarService.openWarningSnackBar(SnackbarMessageComponent);
          }
          else throw error;
        });
  }
```

App Error :

```
export class AppError {
    constructor(public originalError?: any){
        //originalError will contain the original error throw by the server
    }
}
```

App error Handler :

```
export class AppErrorHander implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(
        public snackBarService: SnackbarService, 
        public sharedSnackBarMessage: SharedSnackbarMessageService) { }

    handleError(error: any){
        this.sharedSnackBarMessage.changeMessage("An unexpeted error has occured");
        this.snackBarService.openDangerSnackBar(SnackbarMessageComponent);
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Bad Request Error :

```
import { AppError } from './validators/app-error';

export class BadRequest extends AppError {   
}
```

Not found error :

```
import { AppError } from './validators/app-error';

export class NotFoundError extends AppError {
}
```

Comment: I'll try it right now and keep you updated :)

Comment: Yes it won't work because it's expecting an observable